# Should vs Got to vs Have to

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparative-degree

I understand that when using `have to` in a sentence, the meaning is clear - something needs to be done and there is no choice about it. For example:

> You **have to** have car insurance to drive a car.

However, it would be wrong to say

> You **should** have car insurance to drive a car.

because it would mean that you have a choice.

Is this correct? Is there a degree of how mandatory is the action and can it be changed by using `got to` vs `should` vs `have to`?

Comment: Generally, *have to* and *(have) got to* indicate requirements, and *should* indicates a recommendation. This is why (US) legalese is littered with *must* and *must not* for absolutes, and *may* for optional things. As a side note, insurance is not always required to drive a car, so this may be a poor example to use to indicate a requirement. ;)

Comment: Using _got to_ is just poor grammar.

Comment: @Mick Are you saying *you got to* is poor grammar, or *you have got to* is as well? I agree with the first, not so sure about the second.

Comment: In formal writing it is always *have*, whereas in informal writing and speech *have got* can be used instead of *have*.

Comment: @Davo: Thank you! (I think in Canada we have to have car insurance to drive and not get in trouble :)

Comment: @Mick: Thank you! The whole point of being "here" is to learn something new. I just did thanks to you :)